# Max listeners exceeded when creating react app

Tags: reactjs, npx

When I create a new react app using the following command

```
npx create-react-app ./
```

I get the following error

```
(node:2448) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 close listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

I tried increasing the maximum number of listeners but it didn't solve the problem
I'm using node 20.4.0

Comment: What is your Node.js version?

Comment: I'm using node 20.4.0

Comment: Have written an answer. Can you accept my answer if its ok? Thanks :)

Comment: Create react app is no longer recommended. See here for the list https://react.dev/learn/start-a-new-react-project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Node.js `v20`, you need to downgrade to `v18`.

`create-react-app` do not have support for `v20` (as it supports only upto the latest LTS version, which is `v18`).

That should fix the issue you are seeing.